# Find closed form for roots of trig formula

Tags: equation-solving, summation, trigonometry

I have the expression

```
Sum[(2 j \[Pi] Sin[(2 j \[Pi] x)/(r + 1)])/(r + 1)^2, {j, 0, r}] == 0
```

I want to find the roots in terms of `x` and `r`.

After using `FullSimplify`, and removing expressions that make no contribution to the zeroes (such as integer multiples and the denominator of the fraction that results from `FullSimplify`), I end up with

```
Sin[(\[Pi] x)/(r + 1)] Cos[(\[Pi] (x + 2 r x))/(r + 1)] + Sin[2 π x]==0
```

However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. @KraZug, who was very kindly helping me [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181409/how-can-i-force-results-to-be-expressed-in-exact-fractions-rather-than-approxima), says that the roots appear to have a closed form - and it is true that plotting the results for increasing `r` seem to imply some form of convergence... But I have absolutely no idea how to find an algebraic expression for the roots.

I have tried `FindRoot`, `ToRadicals`, `Solve`... But they all produce error messages and no result. I suspect part of this might be to do with a failure to take limits - but that actually should only affect roots at `x=n r + 1` (where `n` is an integer).

Can anyone suggest how I should proceed?

Comment: `Pi[]`,you mean `Pi=3.141...` ?

Comment: Apologies, yes. See edited version above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this [*closed form*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) by your defintion?

```
Reduce[Sin[(\[Pi] x)/(r + 1)] Cos[(\[Pi] (x + 2 r x))/(r + 1)] + 
   Sin[2 \[Pi] x] == 0]
```

$\left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{r+1}\right)=0\land \sin (2 \pi  x)=0\right)\lor \\
\left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{r+1}\right)\neq 0\land \cos \left(\frac{\pi  (2 r
   x+x)}{r+1}\right)=\sin (2 \pi  x) \left(-\csc \left(\frac{\pi  x}{r+1}\right)\right)\right)$

Comment: Hi. Not sure what the `V` and inverted `V` mean... But when I try `Reduce` I get `Reduce::naqs: 0 is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities.` which then gives `Reduce[0]`.

Comment: `∧` and `∨` are logical $\texttt{and}$ and $\texttt{or}$. Please add the exact code of your attempt to use `Reduce` to your question such that we could help. If you copy & paste mine, you should get the same output in the standard *Mathematica* output form.

Comment: My apologies. I must have made a typo somewhere. Yes, it works. Many thanks.