# Strange answer for Eigenvalues of a 4x4 matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I am getting these strange eigenvalues of this simple looking 4-dimensional matrix:

```
 mymatrix = {{1 - a, -((I Conjugate[b])/Sqrt[2]), b/Sqrt[
    2], -((I a)/2)}, {(I b)/Sqrt[2], a/2, 0, 0}, {Conjugate[b]/Sqrt[
    2], 0, a/2, 0}, {(I a)/2, 0, 0, 0}};
Eigenvalues[mymatrix]
    (**{a/2, Root[
  a^3 + (4 a - 6 a^2 - 8 b Conjugate[b]) #1 + (-8 + 4 a) #1^2 + 
    8 #1^3 &, 1], 
 Root[a^3 + (4 a - 6 a^2 - 8 b Conjugate[b]) #1 + (-8 + 4 a) #1^2 + 
    8 #1^3 &, 2], 
 Root[a^3 + (4 a - 6 a^2 - 8 b Conjugate[b]) #1 + (-8 + 4 a) #1^2 + 
    8 #1^3 &, 3]})
```

What to do with this Root[] stuff?

Comment: Did you look up `Root` in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The following works.

```
mymatrix = {{1 - a, -((I Conjugate[b])/Sqrt[2]), b/Sqrt[
2], -((I a)/2)}, {(I b)/Sqrt[2], a/2, 0, 0}, {Conjugate[b]/Sqrt[
2], 0, a/2, 0}, {(I a)/2, 0, 0, 0}};Eigenvalues[mymatrix]//ToRadicals
```

Addition. I don't see that way in [How to work with Root objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects?)  as well as in the help to `Root`.

Comment: `ToRadicals[]` is mentioned in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126156).

Comment: @J. M. is computer-less: Thank you.