# How to change the form of the answer?

Tags: symbolic, algebra

`Reduce[x^2 + y^3 == z && x + 2 y == 3 z + 1 && x y z != 0, {x, y, z}]`

you get `(y == Root[1 - x + 3 x^2 - 2 #1 + 3 #1^3 &, 1] || 
   y == Root[1 - x + 3 x^2 - 2 #1 + 3 #1^3 &, 2] || 
   y == Root[1 - x + 3 x^2 - 2 #1 + 3 #1^3 &, 3]) && 
 z == 1/3 (-1 + x + 2 y) && -x y + x^2 y + 2 x y^2 != 0`

How can we get rid of #?

Just like `Reduce[6 - 3 x^2 == 2 n^2 + 4 n x, x]`

`x == 1/3 (-2 n - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[9 - n^2]) || 
 x == 1/3 (-2 n + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[9 - n^2])`

Comment: See [Szabolcs' answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126156/5478) in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13767/5478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the output with  [`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html):

```
ToRadicals @ Reduce[x^2 + y^3 == z && x + 2 y == 3 z + 1 && x y z != 0, {x, y, z}]
```

[image]