# How to make version 12 print Root objects to screen normally as in earlier versions?

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, display, boxes

From clean kernel, when typing

```
 result = Reduce[2 d^2 == -((2*(1 + d) + ((4 d^3)/(1 - d)))*(d - 1)),d]
```

Here what version 12 displays on the screen, compared to version 11.3

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Compare to 11.3

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want 12 to display the result like 11.3 did. I know I can apply `InputForm` to the result of 12 to make it display like 11.3, but I do not want to do this each time.

I tried to search options inspector, but not sure what to look for.

Comment: This behavior is the single change in version 12 I most dislike. (Same thing happens with `Solve`, of course.) The default output obfuscates the distinction between exact solutions with numerical approximations. While engineers and other "practical" folks may like the new behavior, I really see no good rationale, and a discrepancy the way even version 12 leaves other irrational quantities as exact expressions.

Comment: `SetSystemOptions[
 "TypesetOptions" -> "NumericalApproximationForms" -> False]`

Comment: @ilian: Is there an option to do this in Option Inspector? If so, where? And if not, why in the world not?

Comment: The option inspector is for FrontEnd options, while the typesetting is the kernel's responsibility here. This command could be placed in the kernel's init.m file if you would like to be executed automatically every time.

Comment: @JasonB For the moment it looks like just `Root` and `AlgebraicNumber`... not sure about future plans. I can make an answer out of the comments, but it's totally fine if someone else beats me to it.

Comment: @murray I'm probably in the "practical folks" category, and I still hate this change. It also seems to me that it confuses beginners more than it helps them.

Comment: I like the fact that `Root` can be displayed more compactly like this, but I think the design could have been _way_ better. I'd much prefer some kind of elided `TraditionalForm` polynomial and a number on the right. i.e. just take the original form and make it more compact.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Making the comments into an an answer as suggested.

> `SetSystemOptions[ "TypesetOptions" -> "NumericalApproximationForms" -> False]`

will restore the legacy typesetting for `Root` and `AlgebraicNumber`.

> This command could be placed in the kernel's init.m file if you would like to be executed automatically every time. (The option inspector is for FrontEnd options)

Comment: Can I configure it to show more decimal digits in iconized form?