# Inversion of a hypergeometric function

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, special-functions, inverse

I have been trying to invert the hypergeometric function 
$$\rho(r)=\frac{2b}{1-q}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac br\right)^{1-q}}\,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1-\frac{1}{q-1};\frac{3}{2};1-\left(\frac br\right)^{1-q}\right)$$

Unfortunately, it cannot be inverted exactly so I tried feeding up the function with random values of $q$ using the routine below

```
rho[r_, b_, q_] := (2 b/(1 - q)) (1 - (b/r)^(1 - q))^(1/2) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1 - 1/(q - 1), 3/2, 1 - (b/r)^(1 - q)]
Solve[rho[r_, b_, q_]==x,r]
```

Luckily, there are two values where this function can be inverted exactly, that is $q=-1$ and $q=1/3$. Is there an effective way or routine to find $q$ values in which the function has an exact inverse? 
By the way, $b$ is just some positive constant while $-\infty<q<1$.

Comment: If this doesn't get answers, maybe Math.SE would have an answer?

Comment: What did you try in Mathematica?

Comment: @Ulrich, I just tried the routine Solve[\rho[r_,b_,q_]==x,r]

Comment: @MichaelE2, noted.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3009945/inverse-of-the-asymptotic-expansion-of-gauss-hypergeometric-function

Comment: Did you attempt its differential equation inverse ?

Comment: @Narasimham I did but no luck...

Comment: You can graph the solutions with something like this: `ContourPlot3D[rho[r, 1, q] == x,
 {x, 0, 3}, {q, -4, 1}, {r, 1, 4},
 ContourStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, ColorData[97][1]]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[x/b], HoldForm[q], HoldForm[r/b]}]`

Comment: How about the $q=0$ case? Can we invert that exactly? It involves inverting an arctanh function. Is there a chance?

Answer (score 2):

**Not full answer.**

We can find more $q$ values in range:`1/3..1`:

```
func = Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1 - 1/(q - 1), 3/2, 1 - (b/r)^(1 - q)] //FullSimplify
(*Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (-2 + q)/(-1 + q), 3/2, 1 - (b/r)^(1 - q)]*)

M = 20;(*You can increase this value*)
sol = Solve[(-2 + q)/(-1 + q) == #/2, q][[1]] & /@ Table[2 x - 1, {x, 3, M}]
(* q values*)

func /. sol // FunctionExpand
(*large expression*)

rho[r_, b_, q_] := (2 b/(1 - q)) (1 - (b/r)^(1 - q))^(1/2)*func
Solve[rho[r, 1, q /. sol[[2]]] == x, r, Reals](*for b=1 ,q=3/5*)

(*{{r -> ConditionalExpression[
Root[-1073741824 - 754974720 x^2 - 212336640 x^4 - 29859840 x^6 - 
   2099520 x^8 - 
   59049 x^10 + (754974720 + 424673280 x^2 + 89579520 x^4 + 
      8398080 x^6 + 295245 x^8) #1^2 + (279183360 + 
      48660480 x^2 - 2877120 x^4 - 590490 x^6) #1^4 + (37219840 - 
      4966920 x^2 + 590490 x^4) #1^6 + (2304855 - 
      295245 x^2) #1^8 + 59049 #1^10 &, 2], x > 0]}}*)
```

Comment: I'll check this out. Thanks

Comment: you did not include the terms outside the hypergeometric function. And that makes the inversion difficult still.

Comment: @user583893. Transcendental equation can't be solved analytically.Try numerics.

Comment: @user583893 Add some conditions on `r` and `x`: `Simplify[
 Table[Solve[
   Simplify[FunctionExpand@rho[r, 1, (qq - 2)/qq], r > 1] == x && 
    r > 1 && x > 0, r], {qq, 1, 2M, 2}],
 x > 0]` for `M` solutions.

Comment: How do I make sense with the Root[...]?

Comment: @user583893 See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects

Comment: I think, I cannot get exact solutions anymore. How bad

Comment: How about the $q=0$ case? Can we invert that exactly? It involves inverting an arctanh function. Is there a chance?

Comment: @user583893.No hope for $q=0$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation