# How this equation is solved in reals

Tags: equation-solving, syntax, code-request

I have tried to solve this equation $2^{-2 ^{2^{-x}}}=2$ using

```
FindInstance[2^(-2^(2^(-x))) == 2, x, Reals]
```

The result is

```
{{x -> Root[{-2 Log[2]^2 + 2^(1 + #1) Log[2]^2 #1 &, 0.64118574450498598449}]}}
```

then find in value of `x^(1/x)`

I understand that the result is 1/2 but I can't prove it.

**What does the # in the result mean?**

Comment: Look up `Root` in the docs and also see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126156/4999

Comment: No real solution exists in the range `-1<x<1` : `NSolve[{2^(-2)^2^(-x) == 2, -1 < x < 1 }, x, Reals] (*{}*)`

Answer (score 3):

For positive real `x`, `x^(1/x) == 1/2` is equivalent to `x == 1/2^x`:

```
x == 1/2^x /.
   {x -> Root[
     {-2 Log[2]^2 + 2^(1 + #1) Log[2]^2 #1 &, 
      0.64118574450498598449}
     ]} // FullSimplify

(*  True  *)
```

Or you can get numerical evidence:

```
N[
 x^(1/x) /.
  {x -> Root[
     {-2 Log[2]^2 + 2^(1 + #1) Log[2]^2 #1 &, 
      0.64118574450498598449}]},
 10]  (* number of digits of precision to compute *)

(*  0.5000000000  *)
```

Comment: `E^(-ProductLog[Log[2]]) == ProductLog[Log[2]]/Log[2] == 
  Root[{-2 Log[2]^2 + 2^(1 + #1) Log[2]^2 #1 &, 
    0.64118574450498598449}] // FullSimplify` evaluates to `True`

Comment: What does the # in the result mean?

Comment: @zeros - `#` ([`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)) is an argument in a pure function. Read the documentation for [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)