# What is the first slot value in this expression?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, slot

I would like to know what is the first slot value in the following expression

`h1 < Root[-c^3 d1^2 + #1^2 (-3 c d1^2 + 6 c d1 d2) + #1 (3 c^2 d1^2 -2 c^2 d1 d2) + #1^3 (d1^2 - 4 d1 d2 + d1^2)  &, 1]`

Comment: I think there is not such an `x` in this case. 
In fact, one can directly copy, paste and execute this command 
`d1 = 1;`    

`d2  = 2;`    
`h1 < Root[-c^3 d1^2 + #1^2 (-3 c d1^2 + 6 c d1 d2) + #1 (3 c^2 d1^2 - 
       2 c^2 d1 d2) + #1^3 (d1^2 - 4 d1 d2 + d1^2) &, 1]` 

obtaining 
`h1 < 1/3 (84 - 28 Sqrt[21])`

Comment: Both `h1, d1, d2` are real positive constants

Comment: @FRANCESCO - you must have also given `c` a value. `Root[-c^3 d1^2 + #1^2 (-3 c d1^2 + 6 c d1 d2) + #1 (3 c^2 d1^2 - 
       2 c^2 d1 d2) + #1^3 (d1^2 - 4 d1 d2 + d1^2) &, 1] /. {d1 -> 1, 
  d2 -> 2, c -> 56}` evaluates to `1/3 (84 - 28 Sqrt[21])`

Comment: I forgot about `c`. `c` is a real positive constant too

Comment: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126156/3066) will explain root objects to you.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st argument of a root object is a pure function, let us call it `pf`, which is why you see the slot object `#1`, which represents the unknown. The 1st argument preserves the information needed to solve the equation `pf[x] == 0` when all the unevaluated symbols in the root object become known quantities.

The 2nd argument is an ordinal identifying which of possibly many roots of the equation this particular root object represents. The ordering is the by the real part of the root (after evaluation — the evaluator evidently finds all the roots).

So, when you resolve all the unevaluated symbols, evaluating the root object returns the numeric value of the root indicated by the 2nd argument.

In your case, if we give `c -> 1, d1 -> 1, d2 -> 1`, then

```
Block[{c, d1, d2},
  Root[
    -c^3 d1^2 + 
    #1^2 (-3 c d1^2 + 6 c d1 d2) + 
    #1 (3 c^2 d1^2 - 2 c^2 d1 d2) + 
    #1^3 (d1^2 - 4 d1 d2 + d1^2) &,
    1]
  /. 
  {c -> 1, d1 -> 1, d2 -> 1}]
```

> `1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5])`

Since the 2nd argument is 1, this must be the smallest real root.

Comment: The fact is that in my case i cannot figure where the function or the block is. The complete command is this:

$\text{Reduce}\left[-\frac{h_1 \left(c-h_1\right) \left(d_1^2 \left(c-h_3\right) \left(2 c-h_1-h_3\right)+d_2 d_1 \left(h_1+h_3\right) \left(2 c-h_1-h_3\right)+d_2^2 h_3 \left(h_1+h_3\right)\right)}{\left(h_1+h_3\right) \left(-2 c+h_1+h_3\right) \left(d_1 \left(c-h_3\right)+d_2 h_1\right) \left(d_1 \left(c-h_1\right)+d_2 h_3\right)}=\frac{1}{2}\land c>0\land h_1>0\land h_3>0\land h_1<c\land h_3<c\land d_1>0\land d_2>0,\left\{h_1,h_3\right\},\mathbb{R}\right]$ .

Comment: The output result starts with $d_1>0 \\ \&\&\left(\left(0<d_2\leq 2 d_1-\sqrt{3} \sqrt{d_1^2}\&\&c>0 \\ \&\&\left(\left(0<h_1<\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^3 \left(d_1^2-4 d_2 d_1+d_2^2\right)+\text{$\#$1}^2 \left(6 c d_1 d_2-3 c d_1^2\right)+\text{$\#$1} \cdot \\ \cdot  \left(3 c^2 d_1^2-2 c^2 d_1 d_2\right)-c^3 d_1^2\&,1\right]\&\&\right.\right.\right.\right. \dots $

Comment: @FRANCESCO. It looks to me that the content of the two above comments should be an edit to your question. They are certainly not appropriate comments to this answer.