# Understanding Root and Solving higher degree polynomials

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I have trouble understanding `Root` in Mathematica.

For instance:

```
Solve[x^5 + 2 x + 1 == 0, x]
```

gives me a strange solution that I don't quite understand. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression like:

```
Root[1 + 2*#1 + #1^5 & , 1, 0]
```

is simply an exact representation of an algebraic number. Radicals like `Sqrt[2]` are more familiar, but cannot express every algebraic number.

You can treat such things pretty much as any other exact representation of a number in *Mathematica*. You can get numeric approximations using `N[]`. However, *Mathematica* is a bit less eager to automatically reduce expressions containing these: arithmetic on these is much more expensive than adding `2+2`. But you can say "pretty please" with `RootReduce[]`.

Once you're used to these, they are liberating. Problems unsolvable with the traditional algebra of radicals gain solutions.

Comment: I see. In essence, it's saying "I have no clue how to solve this system, but if the solution would exist, it would be the nth root of the expression". is that correct ?

Comment: @james - No, it is saying it knows exactly how to solve this problem and the solution is the `Root` expression. Because it knows the exact solution, you can specify any desired working precision with `N`, e.g., `N[#, 100]&`

Comment: @james - Look at `poly = x^5 + 2 x + 1; 

sol = Solve[poly == 0, x]; 

Table[poly /. (sol // N[#, wp] &), {wp, 50, 110, 20}]`

Comment: @james: Algebraic numbers represented as `Root` expressions are well-defined numbers, just like `Sqrt[2]` is.

Comment: @BobHanlon Many thanks for your clarification. Still in the background it uses some kind of numeric method to evaluate the solution, right? I mean, would you be able to solve this "root" without a PC ? This to me is the definition of an "exact solution". Sorry, if I sound pushy. This is not my intention. I am just really interested. Thanks ! :)

Comment: @james: It's like `Sqrt[2]`: if you want an approximate numeric representation, you need an algorithm. But yes, there is the issue that the algorithms for approximating `Root` objects are more complex and less well known. So, if you need approximate numeric representation, use *Mathematica* to obtain it.