# how to transform a decimal into a radical equivalent with minimal error,and find a correct syntax?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, approximation

I have been solving this equation `x^x^x == 36` , *Mathematica* does not give me a solution by applying traditional methods , neither with `Solve` , nor with `Reduce` , and so I've used the Newton-Raphson method and arrived to this approximation `2.10703646396`.

Someone told me that the result is a non-square root , well in particular

- Does anyone know an approach to solve this equation in *Mathematica*?
- Is it possible to find a radical approximation with minimal error?

I have tried

```
Reduce[ x^x^x == 36, x > 0, x]
Solve[ x^x^x == 36, x > 0, x]
```

Comment: Here is the proper syntax: `Reduce[x^x^x == 36 && x > 0, x]` and `Solve[x^x^x == 36 && x > 0, x]` The output of these is a RootObject. MMA can sometimes convert RootObjects to radicals using ToRadicals (see the documentation), but it doesn't seem to work in this case.  I suspect the reason is that ToRadicals is designed for cubics and quartics.  For more background, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/217138/understanding-root-and-solving-higher-degree-polynomials/217139#217139 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects

Comment: @theorist `ToRadicals` will not approximate a radical if given an expression that is not algebraic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symbolic functions like `Reduce` and `Solve` provide an **exact**  solution of the given equation in terms of the `Root` objects.

```
xs = x /. First @ Solve[ x^x^x == 36 && x > 0, x]
```

> ```
> Root[{-36 + #1^#1^#1 & ,
>        2.10703646395674928520879246974369419433`20.601147030102787}]
> ```

This is not an algebraic number and cannot be represented as a root of polynomial with rational coefficients. Nonetheless solutions of transcendental equations represented with `Root` objects are exact as well even though they cannot be represented in terms of radicals. For more detailed discussion of `Root` objects see e.g. [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768)

Our solution `xs` can be numerically approximated with arbitrary precision, e.g.

```
N[ xs, 50]
```

> ```
> 2.1070364639567492852140489758794729541219024075415
> ```

We can also find an **algebraic approximation** of the solution `xs` with `RootApproximant`, e.g. in terms of a root of third order polynomial:

```
RootApproximant[xs, 3] // InputForm
```

> ```
> Root[-9946 + 4127*#1 - 262*#1^2 + 258*#1^3 & , 1, 0]
> ```

```
ToRadicals @ %
```

> ```
> 1/387 (131 + (3850120229 + 15093 Sqrt[98585357943])^(1/3)/2^(2/3) - 
>       1562827/(2 (3850120229 + 15093 Sqrt[98585357943]))^(1/3))
> ```

this is quite a good approximation

```
N[{xs, RootApproximant[xs, 3]}, 17]
```

> ```
>  {2.1070364639567493, 2.1070364639567491}
> ```

Let's represent the solution graphically:

```
Plot[ -Log[36] + Log[x] x^x, {x, 0, 2.5}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

**Warning**

Equation `x^x^x == 36` can be rewritten equivalently as `Exp[x Log[x]] Log[x] - Log[36] == 0`. Solving it with `Reduce` or `Solve` yields another `Root` object which is the same solution even though *Mathematica* does not demonstrate automatically that they are mathematically equal.

Comment: You can show the two `Root` expressions are equal to any desired precision using `With[{wp = 1000}, N[xs, wp] - N[xs2, wp]]`