# Does anyone know how to interpret this solution to a rational equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I was trying to sove this equation to obtain b as a function of a, but I do not understand the answer that Mathematica gives to me. What are the solts # for? and the &,1 in the end?

Equation

```
Flatten[Solve[((3 a + 5 b)^2 (6 a + 11 b) (6 a^2 + 13 a b + 9 b^2))/(
   1296 (a + b)^3 (2 a + b)^2) == 1, b, Reals]]
```

Solution:

```
{b -> Root[-4860 a^5 - 18360 a^4 #1 - 25407 a^3 #1^2 - 
     14223 a^2 #1^3 - 1177 a #1^4 + 1179 #1^5 &, 1]}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange.  In order to learn how to use this site 
[take the tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). When copying equations from a notebook to your question one should format using inline code  by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  It is recommended that you browse [the Markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a!=0` you can transform your equation

```
eq=((3 a + 5 b)^2 (6 a + 11 b) (6 a^2 + 13 a b +9 b^2))/(1296 (a + b)^3 (2 a + b)^2) == 1 /. b -> \[Alpha] a //FullSimplify[#, a > 0] &
(*((3 + 5 \[Alpha])^2 (6 +11 \[Alpha]) (6 + \[Alpha] (13 + 9 \[Alpha])))/(1296 (1 + \[Alpha])^3 (2 + \[Alpha])^2) == 1*)
```

with the new parameter `\[Alpha]=b/a`.

```
Solve[eq, \[Alpha]] // N 
(*{{\[Alpha] ->4.69952}, 
{\[Alpha] -> -0.996298 -0.440207 I},
{\[Alpha] -> -0.996298 +0.440207 I}, 
{\[Alpha] -> -0.854309 -0.0974171 I},
{\[Alpha] -> -0.854309 + 0.0974171 I}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica allows one to write a function on the fly without giving it a name (similar to lambda in Lisp). Say for example that we want to square an argument. There are two ways of writing it on the fly

```
Function[x, x^2][2]
(* 4 *)
```

Another way is using slots and ampersand

```
#^2 &[2]
(* 4 *)
```

The root object you see is using the second syntax.

```
sol = 
 Solve[((3 a + 5 b)^2 (6 a + 11 b) (6 a^2 + 13 a b + 
        9 b^2))/(1296 (a + b)^3 (2 a + b)^2) == 1, b, Reals]
(* {{b -> 
   Root[-4860 a^5 - 18360 a^4 #1 - 25407 a^3 #1^2 - 14223 a^2 #1^3 - 
      1177 a #1^4 + 1179 #1^5 &, 1]}} *)
```

You can evaluate it numerically by replacing `a` with a number applying `N`

You can extract the function from the variable `sol` using `Part` as follows

```
sol[[1]]
(* {b -> 
  Root[-4860 a^5 - 18360 a^4 #1 - 25407 a^3 #1^2 - 14223 a^2 #1^3 - 
     1177 a #1^4 + 1179 #1^5 &, 1]} *)

sol[[1, 1, 2]]
(* Root[-4860 a^5 - 18360 a^4 #1 - 25407 a^3 #1^2 - 
   14223 a^2 #1^3 - 1177 a #1^4 + 1179 #1^5 &, 1] *)
```

Now try use `ReplaceAll`

```
N[sol[[1, 1, 2]] /. a -> 1 ]
(* 4.69952 *)
```