# What is the meaning of this weird square root expression?

Tags: output-formatting

I am using Mathematica to find the eigenvalues of this matrix m

```
m = {{2, I, 1, 2}, {-I, 2, I, 1}, {1, -I, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 2}}
Eigenvalues[m]
```

However, this gives three of the eigenvalues with a strange square root symbol whose meaning I don't understand, and when I hover over it I get even more confused

[image]

I have spent a while trying to figure out what this means, but I just haven't found anything on any forums or in the documentation.

Comment: Search the docs for "root" and "root object".
Apply `N` to get a numeric value.

Comment: The tooltips show that they are expressions with the head `Root`. The documentation can take it from there.

Comment: Perhaps helpful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects

Comment: You can turn off the cute typesetting with ``Unprotect@BoxForm`UseApproximations;
BoxForm`UseApproximations = False;
Protect@BoxForm`UseApproximations;``

Comment: an accurate number. Therefore, MMA gives an expression, whose root is the answer. You may request an approximative answer in form of a machine number by the operator "N".