# Take value from Root that comes from Reduce

Tags: list-manipulation

When I try to solve a transcendental equation such as $e^{-2x}+e^{-3x}=x$ with `Reduce` I use the following:

`Reduce[E^(-2 x) + E^(-3 x) == x, x, Reals]`

With which I get the answer:

```
x == Root[{-1 - E^#1 + E^(3 #1) #1 &, 0.53889837536301031581}]
```

How can I get the root, which is nothing but the 0.538 898… answer I get in the second place of `Root`? I need it to do further calculations, thus, I need the value in a variable.

Comment: `Root` object represents an exact solution and you should not transform it to a numerical approximation in general. In this case you seem to be satisfied with a numerical result however `Root` object is much stronger. More on this subject you can find e.g. in [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var = N[x/.ToRules[Reduce[E^(-2 x) + E^(-3 x) == x, x, Reals] ]]
```

which returns

```
0.538898
```

and assigns the value to `var`

Comment: Sweet. It works smooth. Thanks! I still cannot cast my vote, but this feedback will help.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks. Please be careful with that. Always check to make certain that things are correct in every case. For example, does it do what you expect when `Reduce` returns two roots? Or three? And try to have a good time with this

Comment: Oh, God! I forgot. My approached is generalised if I get two roots.
Example:

`Reduce[E^(0.3*x) + E^(-0.9* x) == x, x, Reals]`

This gave me two answers (with an error related to the inexact coefficients): `x == 1.97921 || x == 5.93163`

So, how can I get both values in different variables?

Comment: Perhaps my warnings helped. That is why I write them. So if you look at the documentation for `ToRules` you should see an example similar to `{ToRules[Reduce[E^(0.3*x) + E^(-0.9* x) == x, x, Reals]]}` and that has turns each of the `==` into `->` Now we want to extract those two values. We do that using this `x/.{ToRules[Reduce[E^(0.3*x) + E^(-0.9* x) == x, x, Reals]]}`  Next, there are serious error messages from Mathematica, and there are other messages that are just cautions. The message you saw was a caution, it said to finish it needed to imagine your decimal constants were exact. OK?

Comment: And `{var1,var2}=x/.{ToRules[Reduce[E^(0.3*x) + E^(-0.9* x) == x, x, Reals]]}` assigns the first value to var1 and the second value to var2. See if you can study the help system and try to figure out why some of this is working. That will help you gain skill and be able to figure out more of your next problem. But there is LOTS to learn. Good luck.