# Solve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete

Tags: equation-solving, integral-transforms

I have such a code:

```
θ[x_] := Boole[x >= 0]
{T, Um} := {10^(-3), 10};
{t1, t2, t3} := {T/2, T/3, T/6};

u1[t_] := Um/t3*(t*θ[t] - (t - t3) θ[t - t3] - (t - t2) θ[t - t2] + (t - t1) θ[t - t1])
U1[s_] := LaplaceTransform[u1[t], t, s]
A1[ω_] := Abs[U1[s]] /. s -> I*ω

NCriterion := 1/10
A1max := Limit[A1[ω], ω -> 0]

ωPetal = Solve[A1[ω] == 0 && ω ∈ Interval[{10000, 20000}], ω][[1]];
ωPetal
ωNCriterion = Solve[A1[ω] == A1max*NCriterion && ω ∈ Interval[{10000, 20000}], ω][[1]];
ωNCriterion
```

When processing `ωPetal` everything is okay but when processing `ωNCriterion` I get a warning:

> Solve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete

and some strange output:
[image: Scary output.]
Why I observe such a behaviour of system and how do I make it process `ωNCriterion` as good as `ωPetal`? Thanks in advance.

**Update: I need exact root value like** `{ω → 5246π}`**, not approximation like** `16480.3`**, which I get with** `NSolve[]` **and** `FindRoot[]`**.**

Comment: Perhaps an interesting comment: NSolve seems to be working fine producing a result equal to 16480.3. This s roughly equal to 5246 Pi.

Comment: Extra comment: FindRoot also works 
FindRoot[A1[\[Omega]] - A1max*NCriterion == 0, {\[Omega], 16000}]

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 Thank you, but how to explain why `Solve[]` gives up and how do I get exact root value as `{ω → 5246π}` or something like that?

Comment: Not really an expert to try and answer this one. Sorry. Perhaps something to do with internal structure of Solve or something related? Be that as it may, you can point out that NSolve and FindRoot give the same answer, and rephrase the question. Perhaps someone else might know :-)

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 Okay, thanks again :)

Comment: The`Root[..]` is the exact answer.  See [the answers here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects) for more about `Root[]` objects.

Comment: Further to @MichaelE2's comment:  Not all solutions to algebraic equations can be expressed as rational numbers (or, in your case, rational multiples of π.)  For example, the equation $x^5 - x + 1 = 0$ doesn't have solutions that can be expressed in terms of roots, fractions, etc.  I suspect that your equation is one of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

θ[x_] := Boole[x >= 0]
{T, Um} = {10^-3, 10};
{t1, t2, t3} = {T/2, T/3, T/6};
```

Using [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) rather than [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) in the definition of `u1` results in the calculation being done once. And [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) will produce a [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) expression.

```
u1[t_] = Um/
    t3*(t*θ[t] - (t - t3) θ[t - t3] - (t - t2) θ[
       t - t2] + (t - t1) θ[t - t1]) // Simplify
```

[image]

Similarly with `U1`

```
U1[s_] = LaplaceTransform[u1[t], t, s]

(* (60000 E^(-s/2000) (-1 + E^(s/6000))^2 (1 + E^(s/6000)))/s^2 *)

A1[ω_] = Abs[U1[s]] /. s -> I*ω;

NCriterion = 1/10;
A1max = Limit[A1[ω], ω -> 0];
```

Instead of `ω ∈ Interval[{10000, 20000}]` use either `Between[ω, {10000, 20000}]` or `10000 <= ω <= 20000`

```
ωPetal = 
 Solve[A1[ω] == 0 && 10000 <= ω <= 20000, ω][[1]]

(* {ω -> 6000 π} *)
```

Note that the RHS of the [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) is no longer a [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html)

```
ωNCriterion = Solve[A1[ω] == A1max*NCriterion && 
    10000 <= ω <= 20000, ω][[1]]
```

[image]

The [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expression is an exact solution. Its approximate numeric value is obtained with [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html)

```
ωNCriterion // N

(* {ω -> 16480.3} *)

Plot[{A1[ω], A1max*NCriterion}, {ω, 10000, 20000},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.7, 0.6}],
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Tooltip @@ 
    N[{Point[{ω, A1[ω]}], {ω, A1[ω]}} /. ωNCriterion]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Will this help me to get `5246π` with `Solve[]`?

Comment: No, since `5246 π` is not the solution. However, if you want to `Round` the solution to the nearest integer multiple of `π`, use `ωNCriterion /. x_?NumericQ :> π*Round[N[x/π]]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat simpler expression for the solution:

```
ωNCriterion /. HoldPattern@Root[{Function[body_], _}] :>
  (6000 ArcCos[x] /. 
    First@Solve[
      body == 0 && -1 < x < 0 /. {#1 -> 6000 ArcCos[x]} // Simplify, 
      x])
% // N
(*
{ω -> 
  6000 ArcCos[
    Root[{
     -ArcCos[#1]^2 + 10 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(-1 + #1)^2 (1 + #1)] &, 
     -0.92304340472946770158}]
    ]}

{ω -> 16480.3}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you. eventually I preferred to solve the problem using `ωNCriterion /. x_?NumericQ :> π*Round[N[x/π]]`.

Comment: @CppNosavvier In that case, `FindRoot` would be faster than `Solve`: `Pi*Round[ω/Pi /.  FindRoot[A1[ω] == A1max*NCriterion, {ω, 15000, 10000, 20000}]]`.  If you want a more accurate solution, you can take more of the terms of the continued fraction: `Pi*FromContinuedFraction[Take[ContinuedFraction[ω/Pi /. FindRoot[A1[ω] == A1max*NCriterion, {ω, 15000, 10000, 20000}]], 3]]`