# Speed up minimization of a high-degree polynomial

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

For fixed $s$ and $n$, I need to find $\alpha$ which minimizes the following expression

$$h (I-2\alpha H + 2\alpha^2 H + \alpha^2 \mathcal{H})^s x0$$
where

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
h&=&(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots,\frac{1}{n}) \\
H&=&\text{diag}(h)\\
\mathcal{H}&=& h\otimes h\\
x0&=& (1,1,\ldots,1)^T
\end{array}
$$

I got the straightforward solution by using `NMinimize`, but it already takes 7 seconds for $n=5$, $s=10$, I'm wondering if there are Mathematica tricks to make this feasible for larger $n$ and $s$

```
CircleTimes = KroneckerProduct;
bestRate[n_, numSteps_] := Module[{},
   ii = IdentityMatrix[n] // N;
   h = Table[i^-1, {i, 1, n}] // N;
   hh = h\[CircleTimes]h;
   H = DiagonalMatrix[h];
   M = ii - 2 alpha H + 2 alpha^2 H.H + alpha^2 hh;
   x0 = ConstantArray[1., {n}];
   xn = MatrixPower[M, numSteps].x0;
   alpha /. Last@NMinimize[xn.h, alpha]
   ];
With[{n = 2},
 Table[bestRate[n, s], {s, 1, 20}]
 ]
```

PS: this is the task of finding optimal rate for Least mean squares filter which runs for $s$ steps, with observations coming from Normal(0,H)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exact root-finding is very fast here:

```
bestRate[n_, numSteps_] := Module[{ii,h,hh,H,M,x0,xn,α},
  ii = IdentityMatrix[n];
  h = 1/Range[n];
  hh = h~KroneckerProduct~h;
  H = DiagonalMatrix[h];
  M = ii - 2 α H + 2 α^2 H . H + α^2 hh;
  x0 = ConstantArray[1, {n}];
  xn = MatrixPower[M, numSteps] . x0;
  α /. Last@Solve[Expand[D[xn . h, α]] == 0, α, Reals]]

With[{n = 2},
  Table[bestRate[n, s], {s, 1, 20}]]

(*    {10/33, 0.30446, 0.30617, 0.308113, 0.310232, 0.312465,
       0.314754, 0.317042, 0.319286, 0.321449, 0.323507, 0.325446,
       0.327256, 0.328938, 0.330493, 0.331927, 0.333246, 0.33446,
       0.335576, 0.336602}                                            *)
```

The results are given as [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects. [Here's an instructive answer on how to work with these](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13767/26598).

```
With[{n = 2},
  DiscretePlot[bestRate[n, s], {s, 1, 100}]]
```

[image]

I think the asymptotic $n=2$ answer for $s\to\infty$ is

```
Root[32 - 288 # + 974 #^2 - 1449 #^3 + 776 #^4 &, 1]
(*    0.356182    *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this work for larger n like n=10? (I'm still on Mathematica 12.1 which is missing SolveValues) Also, curious how you obtained the limiting value

Comment: I've modified the code to use `Solve` instead of `SolveValues`, so it should work for older versions as well.

Comment: I got the asymptote by considering only the largest eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $M$, replacing $M$ by the projector on the associated eigenvector $\vec{v}$, and then looking at the behavior of $\lim_{s\to\infty}\vec{h}\cdot M^s\cdot\vec{x}_0=\lim_{s\to\infty}\lambda^s(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{h})(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{x}_0)$. All these expressions $\lambda$, $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{h}$, and $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{x}_0$, depend on $\alpha$ and we can extract the asymptotic extremum.

Answer (score 5):

For me, using `Simplify` when calculating `xn` greatly reduced the time for minimization. It was clear from using `AbsoluteTiming` that the majority of time was spent during minimization for your use case.

Original code ran in 6.4 seconds with `n=5` and `s=10`. For the same parameters, the following code ran in 0.84 seconds for me. I'm sure there are more quick improvements that are possible by just simplifying the function to optimize.

```
bestRate1[n_, numSteps_] := Module[{}, ii = IdentityMatrix[n] // N;
   h = Table[i^-1, {i, 1, n}] // N;
   hh = h\[CircleTimes]h;
   H = DiagonalMatrix[h];
   M = ii - 2 alpha H + 2 alpha^2 H.H + alpha^2 hh;
   x0 = ConstantArray[1., {n}];
   xn = Simplify[MatrixPower[M, numSteps].x0];
   alpha /. Last@NMinimize[xn.h, alpha]];
```

Things that were tried but didn't do much

1. Using `ParallelTable`. I doubt this is useful for you since you probably don't plan on setting `n=1000`.
2. Using `FullSimplify` at various stages (i.e. `M`, `xn`). Took too long.
3. Using `Refine` at various stages (i.e. `M`, `xn`). Probably didn't do any worthwhile simplification from the perspective of the optimizer.

Another thing you could try out is using a different minimization method. `NelderMead` and `DifferentialEvolution` seem to give similar results. But for the values you had, `SimulatedAnnealing` and `RandomSearch` showed marginal improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I would black-box the objective function so that the matrix powering does not happen symbolically. Also I would use a vector as third argument of the matrix power step. These steps really do not help much for small `s` and `n` but can make a big difference as one or both grow.

```
makeMat[n_, alf_] := Module[
  {h, H},
  h = 1./Range[n];
  H = DiagonalMatrix[h];
  IdentityMatrix[n] - 2 alf H + 2 alf^2 H . H + 
   alf^2*KroneckerProduct[h, h]
  ]

objfunc[mat_?(MatrixQ[#, NumberQ] &), s_Integer] := 
 With[{n = Length[mat]}, 
  MatrixPower[mat, s, ConstantArray[1., {n}]] . (1/Range[n])]

bestRate2[n_, s_] := Module[
  {mat, alf},
  mat = makeMat[n, alf];
  alf /. Last[NMinimize[objfunc[mat, s], alf]]
  ]
```

Test at larger values of `s`:

```
In[39]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 With[{n = 2}, Table[bestRate2[n, s], {s, 26, 50}]]]

(* Out[39]= {1.79803, {0.341282, 0.341872, 0.34242, 0.342931, 0.343407, 
  0.343852, 0.344269, 0.344659, 0.345026, 0.34537, 0.345695, 0.346002,
   0.346291, 0.346565, 0.346824, 0.34707, 0.347303, 0.347525, 0.34774,
   0.347937, 0.348129, 0.348311, 0.348488, 0.348655, 0.348811}} *)
```

The original version took 33.3 seconds on the same machine.