# How to interpret the result of minimization?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Using `Simplify[Minimize[{term2, b >= c > b/2 >= 0 && a >= d > a/2 >= 0}, {c,d}]]` I was able to get the following output:

[image]

I am now wondering how to properly interprete the result. On the left hand side I can see that there are three possible minimized values of the expression. But then, $c$ and $d$ have only two results. Also since, there is the # sign in the $c$ value, what does it mean? Were we able to find a solution or not really? Sorry for asking super basic questions. It's just I couldn't find a nice explanation online.

Comment: For $c$, the slot signs `#` are just additional variables in the `Root` expression - i.e $c$ is the root of that multinomial in variables $a, b, \#_1$

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126156/4999 for a discussion of `Root`.

Comment: I also was lost on which line for the value corresponds to which line of the solution for $c$ and $d$. Since there was a discrepancy in the number of lines (three vs. two). But I think I understand the way Mathematica prints the solutions, I just need to read the conditions right to the solutions more carefully.

Comment: Each `Piecewise` expression tells you explicitly the domain for each of its values. Note that when posting questions include **all** code and data (both in copy and paste-able `InputForm`) needed to reproduce the results. Without the definition of `term2` we cannot produce results that we can read.