# How can I solve an equation numerically for a range of x-values and multiple initial root guesses?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

The following implicitly defined equation has both real and complex roots:

$$
\frac{0.5}{(y + x)^2 - 0.3x^2} + \frac{0.5}{(y - x)^2 - 0.3x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2} = 1
$$

I am trying to solve it numerically using `FindRoot` for a range of x-values. For the initial guesses, I am using `Solve`. The equation has four solutions, namely,  $y_1, y_2, y_3$, and $y_4$,

Here is my attempt:

```
F[y_, x_] :=  0.5/((y - x)^2 - 0.3*x^2) + 0.5/((y - x)^2 - 0.3*x^2) - 1/x^2 - 1

Intialguess = Grid[y /. Table[Solve[F[y, K] == 0, y], {K, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]]

Table[FindRoot[F[y, k] == 0, {y, Intialguess}], {k, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]
```

Output:

```
Out[1] =
 -0.19094    0. - 0.0236008 I   0. + 0.0236008 I   0.19094
 -0.380117   0. - 0.0450256 I   0. + 0.0450256 I   0.380117
 -0.566053   0. - 0.062029 I    0. + 0.062029 I    0.566053
 -0.747747   0. - 0.0720716 I   0. + 0.0720716 I   0.747747
 -0.924725   0. - 0.0715281 I   0. + 0.0715281 I   0.924725
 -1.09698    0. - 0.0515827 I   0. + 0.0515827 I   1.09698
 -1.26484    -0.0550617         0.0550617          1.26484
 -1.42884,   -0.112579          0.112579           1.42884
 -1.58956    -0.163747          0.163747           1.58956
 -1.74762    -0.214101          0.214101           1.74762

in search specification {y,Intialguess} is not a number or array of \
numbers. >>

{FindRoot[F[y, k, U1, U2] == 0, {y, Intialguess}],
 FindRoot[F[y, k, U1, U2] == 0, {y, Intialguess}],
 FindRoot[F[y, k, U1, U2] == 0, {y, Intialguess}],
 FindRoot[F[y, k, U1, U2] == 0, {y, Intialguess}],
 FindRoot[F[y, k, U1, U2] == 0, {y, Intialguess}],
 FindRoot[F[y, k, U1, U2] == 0, {y, Intialguess}],
 FindRoot[F[y, k, U1, U2] == 0, {y, Intialguess}],
 FindRoot[F[y, k, U1, U2] == 0, {y, Intialguess}],
 FindRoot[F[y, k, U1, U2] == 0, {y, Intialguess}],
 FindRoot[F[y, k, U1, U2] == 0, {y, Intialguess}]}
```

The first, second, third, and fourth columns of the grid of initial guesses containing real and complex-valued solutions represents $y_1, y_2, y_3$, and $y_4$, respectively. How do I convert the initial guesses so that `FindRoot` recognises each grid entry as a numeric value?

Goal: Produce a table of numerically solved-roots:

```
    x        y1             y2                y3             y4
   0.1    -0.19494   0. - 0.0236008 I   0. + 0.0236008 I   0.19094
   0.2    -0.380117  0. - 0.0450256 I   0. + 0.0450256 I   0.380117
   0.3    -0.566053  0. - 0.062029 I    0. + 0.062029 I    0.566053
   0.4    -0.747747  0. - 0.0720716 I   0. + 0.0720716 I   0.747747
   0.5    -0.924725  0. - 0.0715281 I   0. + 0.0715281 I   0.924725
   0.6    -1.09698   0. - 0.0515827 I   0. + 0.0515827 I   1.09698
   0.7    -1.26484     -0.0550617        0.0550617         1.26484
   0.8    -1.42884,    -0.112579         0.112579          1.42884
   0.9    -1.58956     -0.163747         0.163747          1.58956
   1.0    -1.74762     -0.214101         0.214101          1.74762
```

and plot the results.

Comment: Are you aware that [`Root` objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13767/26598) can enumerate polynomial roots exactly? [See documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I am not looking for an exact solution, rather a numerical one because the equation does not have an exact solution.

Comment: @Jacob `Grid`is only a formating option, don't use it in `Intialguess = Grid[...]`

Comment: Applying [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) to any exact solution converts it to a numerical solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

F[y_, x_] = 
  0.5/((y - x)^2 - 0.3*x^2) + 0.5/((y - x)^2 - 0.3*x^2) - 1/x^2 - 1;
```

Solving for `y` given `x`

```
tab = Table[
   {x, SolveValues[F[y, x] == 0, y]} //
    Flatten,
   {x, DeleteCases[Range[-1, 1, 0.1], 0.]}];

Dimensions@tab

(* {20, 3} *)
```

Verifying columns 1 and 2

```
And @@ (Chop[F[#[[2]], #[[1]]]] == 0 & /@ tab)

(* True *)
```

Verifying columns 1 and 3

```
And @@ (Chop[F[#[[3]], #[[1]]]] == 0 & /@ tab)

(* True *)

Prepend[tab, {x, Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2]}] // Grid
```

[image]

Plotting,

```
ContourPlot[F[y, x] == 0,
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -2, 2},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, y}),
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Red, Point[tab[[All, {1, 2}]]],
   Green, Point[tab[[All, {1, 3}]]]},
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[
   PointLegend[{Red, Green},
    {Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2]}],
   {.3, .8}]]
```

[image]

Comment: There are complex solutions too!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann - For a fixed `x` (as shown in the table of desired output) there are only two solutions (solutions are real for real `x`). Evaluate `Length@SolveValues[F[y, x] == 0 // Rationalize, y]` To get four solutions, you would need to fix `y` and solve for `x`, i.e., `Length@SolveValues[F[y, x] == 0 // Rationalize, x]` You get equivalent results using `Reduce` in place of `Solve`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Check your function `F[y,x]`, OP posted different formulas in code and LaTeX. That's why there exist two or four solutionbranches

Comment: @UlrichNeumann - I used the definition that the OP posted as code (that can be copied and pasted, LaTeX cannot).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Grid`  in  `Intialguess = Grid[...]` , it is only a formating option!

Try

```
Intialguess =  
Table[{K, y} /. Solve[F[y, K] == 0, y], {K, 0.1,1, 0.1}] // Quiet //Flatten[#, 1] &

Map[Join[#, {y} /.FindRoot[F[y, #[[1]]] == 0, {y,#[[2]]}]] &, Intialguess ]  

(*{{0.1, -0.0135825, -0.0135825}, {0.1, 0.213583,0.213583}, {0.2, -0.0246365, -0.0246365}, 
{0.2, 0.424636,0.424636}, {0.3, -0.0310118,-0.0310118}, 
{0.3, 0.631012,0.631012}, {0.4, -0.0311972, -0.0311972},...}*)
```

result shows, there is  no improvement using initialguess together with FindRoot!

Comment: Thank you @UlrichNeumann, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = 1/2/((y + x)^2 - 3/10*x^2) + 1/2/((y - x)^2 - 3/10*x^2) - 1/x^2 - 1;
sol = y /. Solve[{expr == 0, 0 < x <= 1}, y, WorkingPrecision -> 25];

TableForm[
  Chop@
    Table[
      DeleteCases[Flatten@{N@x, sol}, Undefined], {x, 1/10, 1, 1/10}
    ],
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"x", "y1", "y2", "y3", "y4"}}
]
```

[image: table of results]

---

Note the following:

1. I think you have a wrong sign in your posted code for the expression `F`: it does not match with your $\LaTeX$ expression and with the results you sought. I used the form from your formula.
2. I switched to arbitrary precision (changed the 0.5 -> 1/2 etc) to clean up the results.
3. It looks like you need more than machine precision to get accurate
   results in these calculations. I've included that too.

Comment: noted, your answer is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @MarcoB   `(sol = y /. Solve[{expr == 0 }, y ], 
Table[ {x, sol} , {x, 1/10, 1, 1/10}] // N) ` gives the complete set of solutions including `x==1`