# How to solve combination problem with mathematica?

Tags: combinatorics

How to find the smallest n s.t:

$$\binom{2500-n}{50}/\binom{2500}{50} < 0.5$$

Comment: Just try all possible n: `Catch[For[i = 0, i <= 2500, If[Binomial[2500 - i, 50] < 1/2 Binomial[2500, 50], Throw[i]]; ++i]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

NArgMin[{n, Binomial[2500 - n, 50]/Binomial[2500, 50] < 0.5}, n] // 
  Ceiling // Quiet

(* 35 *)
```

**EDIT:** Or

```
ArgMin[{n, Binomial[2500 - n, 50]/Binomial[2500, 50] < 1/2, n > 0}, 
   n, Integers] // Quiet

(* 35 *)
```

Check,

```
Binomial[2500 - #, 50]/Binomial[2500, 50] & /@ {34, 35, 36} // N

(* {0.500818, 0.490663, 0.480711} *)
```

Comment: In the context of Binomial, isn't the domain automatically set to Integer in mathematica?

Comment: No. `Gamma` or `Factorial` or `Binomial` are defined for real or complex arguments. Evaluate `Binomial[5.3, 3.6]`

Comment: What does `Binomial[5.3, 3.6]` mean?

Comment: `Binomial[m, n] // FunctionExpand` evaluates to `Gamma[1 + m]/(Gamma[1 + m - n] Gamma[1 + n])`

Comment: Why is your usage of `ArgMin` not documented on https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArgMin.html?q=ArgMin?

Comment: It is. The third form shows the use of constraints and the last form shows use of a domain.

Comment: Isn't `domain` also a `constraint`, what's the difference?

Comment: See the documentation for details on the constraints ("The constraints cons can be any logical combination of:") and domain ("Possible domains rdom include:")

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach:

```
expression = Binomial[2500 - n, 50]/Binomial[2500, 50];
Min@ SolveValues[FunctionExpand[expression] < 1/2, n, Integers]

(* Out: 35 *)
```

Comment: Can you explain the usage of `Min@`(why @) and `FunctionExpand`(why is it needed) and the difference between `SolveValues` and `Solve`?

Comment: @omg `@` is a prefix notation for function application. In other words, `f[x]` can also be written as `f@x`. See the "Short Forms" section [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Syntax.html). `FunctionExpand` is needed because it didn't work without it :-) I assume because `Solve` doesn't know how to transform the binomials on its own. [`SolveValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveValues.html) is equivalent to `Solve`, but it returns the *values* of the solutions rather than replacement rules. Compare `Solve[x - 2 == 0, x]` and `SolveValues[x - 2 == 0, x]`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! BTW, how to plot `Binomial[2500 - n, 50]/Binomial[2500, 50]` for integer domain?

Comment: @omg `DiscretePlot[Binomial[2500 - n, 50]/Binomial[2500, 50], {n, 1, 150}]`

Answer (score 2):

Working in $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$, we can ask

```
Reduce[Binomial[2500 - n, 50]/Binomial[2500, 50] < 1/2, n, Reals] // RootReduce

(*    34.0798 < n < 4916.92    *)
```

The results are given as [`Root` objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13767/26598) (zeros of degree-50 polynomials) that can be converted to real numbers with [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html).