# Confused by SolveValues Output

Tags: equation-solving, output

When I plug in an equation involving [`ArcSin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcSin.html) to [`SolveValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveValues.html), I get a result involving [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) and a pure function, with the answer embeded.

Here is a simplified version of the equation:

```
SolveValues[1 == a ArcSin[a], a, Assumptions -> 0 <= a <= 1 ]
```

Output:

```
{
Root[{
   -1 + ArcSin[#] # &, 
   0.89753946128048718439307346196209434156`20.300813366021398
    }]
}
```

The long string of digits is the answer I want, but why is it given inside this expression, and how to I get it out?

Comment: Try this: `FindRoot[1 == a ArcSin[a], {a, 0.5}]`.

Comment: The `Root` expression is the **exact** solution, i.e., an exact number. Like any other exact number (e.g., `Sin[2]`), use `N` to convert it to an approximate value.

Comment: I know the first part, I was including it in an answer to my own post! The second part is what I didn't know

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects

Comment: Thanks for that reference, @MichaelE2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSolveValues[1 == a ArcSin[a] && 0 <= a <= 1, a]
(*{0.8975394612804872`}*)
```

Or, as @Bob Hanlon points out:

```
SolveValues[1 == a ArcSin[a], a, Assumptions -> 0 <= a <= 1] // N
(*{0.8975394612804872`}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, the [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) function "`Root[{f,c}]`
represents the exact root of the general equation `f[x] = 0` near `x = c`."

Since `` 0.89753946128048718439307346196209434156`20.300813366021398 `` is not an exact answer,

```
{
Root[{
   -1 + ArcSin[#] # &, 
   0.89753946128048718439307346196209434156`20.300813366021398
    }]
}
```

is given to specify the exact answer, which occurs near 0.8975...