# Problem with Non-Fermi Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to evaluate the integral to get (B4) as given below.
[image]

My attempt is as follows.

```
f = t/(t^3 + t + y)

f1 = Assuming[y > 0, Integrate[f, {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]]
```

And then integrating over the variable `y`.

Unfortunately, the result I am getting is not sensible, as shown below
[image]

Where it should the function `h`. Can someone make comments on what I have done wrong here?

Comment: How is $h$ defined? Asking because one could define $h(x) = \int_0^x dy \int_0^\infty dt\frac{t}{t^3+t+y}$, for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: Using `Integrate[t/(t^3+t+y),{t,0,Infinity},{y,0,x},Assumptions->x>=0]` also your 2-dimensional integral is given as a `RootSum`. This can be expressed in terms of non-`Root` things using `RootSum[x+#+#^3&,...] // Normal // ToRadicals`.

Comment: With  **Hypergeometric** function:`(2 \[Pi] Hypergeometric2F1[1/6, 2/3, 1/3, -(4/(27 y^2))])/(
 3 Sqrt[3] y^(1/3)) + (
 2 \[Pi] Hypergeometric2F1[5/6, 4/3, 5/3, -(4/(27 y^2))])/(
 27 Sqrt[3] y^(5/3)) - 
 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1, 1}, {2/3, 4/3}, -(4/(27 y^2))]/(3 y)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes calculating symbolically hard multiple integrals changing the order of integration with respect to different variables appears to be helpful and this is the case here (this concerns *version 13.0* and earlier, I guess that the similar situation is in *version 13.1*). Here at first it is calculated with respect to $y$ and than with respect to $t$ (unlike in traditional notation):

```
int = Integrate[t/(t^3 + t + y), {t, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, x}, Assumptions -> x > 0]
```

[image]

Otherwise integrating as in original question we get at the first step `RootSum` object which cannot be calculated (at the present version) symbolically integrating with respect to the second variable.
Calculating at first the integrand with respect to $y$ we get:

```
Assuming[ x > 0 && t > 0, 
  FullSimplify[ Integrate[ t/(t^3 + t + y), {y, 0, x}]]]
```

> ```
> t Log[(t + t^3 + x)/(t + t^3)]
> ```

and then we obtain the result expressed with `RootSum` object, which is analogous to [`Root`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects) object, the both functions are very useful and one should master their usage aiming at symbolic results. `RootSum` should be considered as an exact solution and then it can be transformed symbolically with powerful symbolic functions of the system. Here e.g. we find first terms of a series expansion of the integral

```
Series[ int, {x, 0, 3}] // Normal
```

> ```
> Pi x/2 - 5 Pi x^3/16 + 1/2 x^2 Log[x]
> ```

and we can compare its behaviour with respect to the identity function i.e. $x$ and  w.r.t $\sqrt{x}$:

```
Plot[{int, x, Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Let's see where $int(x)$ equals to $x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ respectively:

```
x /. FindRoot[-(1/2) RootSum[
    x + #1 + #1^3 &, (3 x Log[-#1] #1 + 2 Log[-#1] #1^2)/(
     1 + 3 #1^2) &] == #, {x, 2}] & /@ {x, Sqrt[x]} // Chop
```

> ```
>  {2.19703, 0.679828}
> ```

The above  calculations show how you can start dealing with the result of the integral which couldn't be expressed in simper form without `RootSum`.
These calculations are numerically equal regardless of the order of integration when we evaluate integrals numerically.

Answer (score 1):

the rootsum can be converted to radicals that look quite messy, even after simplification and complexexpand with some abbreviations (r,s,t):

```
s = Sqrt[4 + 27*g^2]; r = s^2 - 3*Sqrt[3]*g*s - 2; 
t = (2/r)^(1/6)*Sqrt[2 + 2^(1/3)*r^(2/3)]; 

h[g_] := (1/(6*(2 - 2^(2/3)*r^(1/3) + 
     2^(1/3)*r^(2/3))))*((Pi*(27*2^(1/6)*Sqrt[3]*
       g^2*(2^(2/3) - 2^(1/3)*r^(1/3) + r^(2/3))*r^(1/6) - 
      2*Sqrt[3]*(2 - 2^(1/3)*r^(2/3))*s + 
       9*g*(4 - 2*2^(2/3)*r^(1/3) + 2*2^(1/3)*r^(2/3) + 
         2^(1/6)*r^(5/6)*s)))/s - 
      ((18*g*(2*2^(1/6)*r^(5/6) + 4*s - 2^(2/3)*r^(1/3)*s) - 
      27*Sqrt[3]*
       g^2*(8 - 2*2^(2/3)*r^(1/3) - 2^(5/6)*r^(1/6)*s + 
         Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[r]*s) - 8*Sqrt[3]*(2 - 2^(1/3)*r^(2/3)) - 
              243*Sqrt[2]*g^3*(2^(1/3) - r^(1/3))*r^(1/6))*
    ArcTan[(Sqrt[3]*(2^(1/3) + r^(1/3)))/(2^(1/3) - 
        r^(1/3))])/(4 - 3*g*(Sqrt[3]*s - 9*g)) + 
      (2 - 2^(2/3)*r^(1/3) + 2^(1/3)*r^(2/3))*
  Log[(54*r)/(2 - r)^2] + (((3*Sqrt[3]*g)*(2^(1/3) - r^(1/3))*
       r^(1/6))/Sqrt[2] + 2^(2/3)*r^(1/3))*
  Log[(t^2 - 4)/(t^2 + 2)]); 

Plot[{NIntegrate[tt/(tt^3 + tt + y), {tt, 0, 1000}, {y, 0, g}], 
h[g]}, {g, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}]
```

[image]