# What does that output of DSolve mean?

Tags: differential-equations

Solving in 13.2 on Windows 10 an ODE

```
DSolve[4*y''[x] + Tanh[x]*y'[x]*2 == (Cosh[x] - 6/Cosh[x]^2)*y[x],  y[x], x]//InputForm
```

, I obiain

> `{{{y[x] -> C[2]*DifferentialRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalX]},  {(-1 - 3*\[FormalX]^2 + 48*\[FormalX]^3 - 3*\[FormalX]^4 - \[FormalX]^6)*\[FormalY][\[FormalX]] +  (4*\[FormalX]^2 + 16*\[FormalX]^4 + 12*\[FormalX]^6)*Derivative[1][\[FormalY]][ \[FormalX]] + 8*\[FormalX]^3*(1 + \[FormalX]^2)^2*Derivative[2][\[FormalY]][ \[FormalX]] == 0, \[FormalY][1] == 0, Derivative[1][\[FormalY]][1] ==  1}], Function[\[FormalX], {{Re[\[FormalX]] <= 0, Im[\[FormalX]] == 0}}]][ E^x] + C[1]*DifferentialRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalX]},  {(-1 - 3*\[FormalX]^2 + 48*\[FormalX]^3 - 3*\[FormalX]^4 - \[FormalX]^6)*\[FormalY][\[FormalX]] +  (4*\[FormalX]^2 + 16*\[FormalX]^4 + 12*\[FormalX]^6)*Derivative[1][\[FormalY]][ \[FormalX]] + 8*\[FormalX]^3*(1 + \[FormalX]^2)^2*Derivative[2][\[FormalY]][ \[FormalX]] == 0, \[FormalY][1] == 1, Derivative[1][\[FormalY]][1] ==  0}], Function[\[FormalX], {{Re[\[FormalX]] <= 0, Im[\[FormalX]] == 0}}]][ E^x]}}`

The above output is unclear to me, especially the part `Function[\[FormalX], {{Re[\[FormalX]] <= 0, Im[\[FormalX]] == 0}}]][ E^x]}}` in both terms. [The documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferentialRoot.html?q=DifferentialRoot) says

> DifferentialRoot[lde,pred] represents a solution restricted to avoid cuts in the complex  plane defined by pred[z], where pred[z] can contain equations and inequalities

, but

```
 DSolve[4*y''[x] + Tanh[x]*y'[x]*2 == (Cosh[x] - 6/Cosh[x]^2)*y[x],  y[x], x, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals] //InputForm
```

produces the same result. The command of Maple `dsolve(4*(diff(y(x), x, x))+2*tanh(x)*(diff(y(x), x)) = (cosh(x)-6/cosh(x)^2)*y(x), y(x))` crashes my comp.

Comment: My **Maple**  give answer with `DESol`, just can't solve(with no Crash)

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Thank you. Maple's `DESol` is an equivalent of `DifferentialRoot` in Mathematica.

Comment: The complex form of the DE, in terms of $x(t)=re^{it}$,  has a $1/r$ term creating a ramified singularity at the origin.  Mathematica  I suspect is assigning the negative real axis as an arbitrary  branch cut to restrict the multivalued solution to a single-valued solution.

Comment: @josh: Can you kindly ground your claim?

Comment: @user64494:  I'll make a post in a day or so unless someone does so before.

Comment: @user64494:  I made a mistake interpreting the DE.  My comment above is not correct.  Apology  for the distraction.

Answer (score 7):

`DSolve` was able to determine that the solution is a function that satisfies a holonomic ODE composed with `Exp[x]`. The result returned reflects this, and moreover is a computable object -- rather than only just reporting that the ODE it satisfies.

What I mean by that is, just like [`Root`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects) objects, you can perform operations on them:

```
res = DSolveValue[
  4*y''[x] + Tanh[x]*y'[x]*2 == (Cosh[x] - 6/Cosh[x]^2)*y[x], 
  y[x], 
  x
] /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 0};
```

Various operations:

```
D[res, x]
```

> ```
> E^x DifferentialRoot[(* different ODE commented out... *)][E^x]
> ```

```
res /. x -> 1.0
```

> ```
> 0.555421
> ```

```
Plot[res, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

See the Applications section in the `DifferentialRoot` ref page for more examples [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferentialRoot.html#1785556135).

So despite not knowing an explicit solution to the ODE in terms of elementary/special functions, we at least now have a function that satisfies a simpler ODE (composed with `Exp[x]`) that is computable. Much better than `DSolve` coming back unevaluated IMO.

---

As for the second argument `Function[x, {{Re[x] <= 0, Im[x] == 0}}]`, it looks as if it's restricting the `DifferentialRoot` object to avoid a branch cut that is a ray starting at the origin, pointing along the negative real axis.

To see this, notice that its plot in the complex plane is restricted to the right half plane:

Just examine the `DifferentialRoot` object alone:

```
res2 = res /. Exp[x] -> x;
```

Plot it:

```
ComplexPlot[res2, {x, 2}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

We can see the branch cut by tricking the object into thinking there is nothing to avoid:

```
res3 = res2 /. Re[z_] <= 0 :> Re[z] <= -∞;

ComplexPlot[res3, {x, 2}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

---

It looks like there are multiple branch cuts in the left half plane, which is probably why the restriction is that entire region. However it looks like the ODE satisfies the `DSolve`'s return value anywhere away from the cuts:

```
res4 = res /. Re[z] <= 0 :> Re[z] <= -\[Infinity];

zero = 4*D[res4, {x, 2}] + Tanh[x]*D[res4, x]*2 - (Cosh[x] - 6/Cosh[x]^2)*res4;

zero /. x -> -1.0 - I
```

> ```
> -7.98108*10^-7 - 1.16422*10^-6 I
> ```

```
zero /. x -> -1.0 + .0001I
```

> ```
> 9.1255*10^-7 - 1.94541*10^-7 I
> ```

It's tough to see, but here are 2 more cuts in the plot above:
[image]

And we can plot the absolute value along the line segment with end points `-2` and `2I` to see the jump caused by the cut:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Abs[res3[[0]][-2 (1 - t) + 2 I t]]], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 2.5}]
```

[image]

#### Edit

The branch cuts seem to be rays starting at each singularity (in this case $0$, $\pm i$) in the direction parallel to the line segment between $1$ and each singularity, respectively. I think this makes sense since the initial conditions are at `x == 1`, and so integrating along a path that hits a singularity will cause problems.

My guess is then that the smallest (left) half plane is chosen that contains all singularities, which is then therefore guaranteed to restrict away from any branch cuts.

Comment: Thank you. You mostly repeat the documentation for the ODE under consideration. Unfortunately, your "As for the second argument Function[x, {{Re[x] <= 0, Im[x] == 0}}], it looks as if it's restricting the DifferentialRoot object to avoid a branch cut that is a ray starting at the origin, pointing along the negative real axis" does not explain the result of `resu = DSolveValue[
    4*y''[x] + Tanh[x]*y'[x]*2 == (Cosh[x] - 6/Cosh[x]^2)*y[x], y[x], 
    x] /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 1};Plot[resu, {x, -5, 5}]` and `ComplexPlot[resu,{x,-2-2*I,2+2*I},PerformanceGoal->"Speed"]`. Sorry, this is not it.

Comment: I'd like to add that your attempt of the explanation "As for the second argument Function[x, {{Re[x] <= 0, Im[x] == 0}}], it looks as if it's restricting the DifferentialRoot object to avoid a branch cut that is a ray starting at the origin, pointing along the negative real axis" simply  elaborates "DifferentialRoot[lde,pred] represents a solution restricted to avoid cuts in the complex plane defined by pred[z], where pred[z] can contain equations and inequalities"

Comment: That is because `resu` is a `DifferentialRoot` object composed with `Exp[x]`. Look at `resu /. Exp[x] -> x` and you'll see similar behavior.

Comment: Can you kindly explain the reason to consider `resu /. Exp[x] -> x ` instead of `resu`?

Comment: Isn't that the point of answering this question? I elaborated on that exact note, explaining what it means. What else are you looking for?

Comment: GregHurst(@ does not work) :Sorry, you avoid an answer. Any composed `DifferentialRoot` is not described in the documentation.

Comment: Because this creates a `DifferentialRoot` object not composed with anything else. It shows the behavior of that object alone, and so we can reason about its behavior.

Comment: Then I suppose I don't understand what you're looking for. Maybe make your question more clear next time.

Comment: I repeat that the speculation "As for the second argument Function[x, {{Re[x] <= 0, Im[x] == 0}}], it looks as if it's restricting the DifferentialRoot object to avoid a branch cut that is a ray starting at the origin, pointing along the negative real axis." explains nothing.

Comment: I elaborate more directly below. I'm done talking with you -- you just give terse, non-constructive feedback. I'm not going to interact with you on this site anymore.