Solve with message: DifferentialRoot with no explicit branch cuts
I need to solve the following differential equation
FE2sim2 = (2 B (3 B - 2 b0)^2 W[ r] - (3 B - 2 r)^3 r (4 W'[r] + r W''[r]))/(r^2 (-3 B +  2 r)^3);

where 0<B<2b0/3, b0>0, r>=b0. So when I try to solve it, as follows
SolW2 = DSolve[FE2sim2 == 0, W[r], r];

I do not get a solution, but the following message:

What does it mean? I think that it is not able to solve the ODE, because at the denominator this expression (-3 B + 2 r) can be zero. I tried also to put assumptions about the variable ranges I have written above, but still I am not able to solve it. Can you please help me in fixing this issue?

Maple 2024 produces W(r) = c__1*sqrt(1 + 18*B*(B - (2*b0)/3)^2*r^2)*exp(sqrt(-2*B*(3*B - 2*b0)^2)*r)*sqrt(3*sqrt(2)*B^(3/2)*r - 2*sqrt(2)*sqrt(B)*r*b0 + I)/(r^3*sqrt(3*I*sqrt(2)*B^(3/2)*r - 2*I*sqrt(2)*sqrt(B)*r*b0 + 1)) + c__2*sqrt(1 + 18*B*(B - (2*b0)/3)^2*r^2)*exp(-sqrt(-2*B*(3*B - 2*b0)^2)*r)*sqrt(3*I*sqrt(2)*B^(3/2)*r - 2*I*sqrt(2)*sqrt(B)*r*b0 + 1)/(r^3*sqrt(3*sqrt(2)*B^(3/2)*r - 2*sqrt(2)*sqrt(B)*r*b0 + I))

Thank you very much, I will check this solution. What does it mean "I"?

In your definition of FE2sim2 is a bracket missing.  Should it red: FE2sim2 = (2 B (3 B - 2 b0)^2 W[ r] - (3 B - 2 r)^3 r (4 W'[r] + r W''[r]))/(r^2 (-3 B +  2 r)^3);

Yes, sorry I have missed a bracket. I have checked your equation and it is correct

Please fix the simple mistake pointed out by Daniel, the question will be reopened once it meets the standard of the site.

A differential root is a symbolic representation of the exact solution in terms of a holonomic function. It can be used like any other algebraic expression.

"I do not get a solution, but the following message:" This isn't quite accurate, what you've seen should be something like this: https://i.sstatic.net/z9S3yS5n.png This is the new-introduced 2D form of DifferentialRoot. (You can transform it to 1D form by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I BTW. ) As to DifferentialRoot, see discussion in e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/279706/1871 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65182/1871
