# Solve[] command returns complex-valued solutions when working with large numbers

Tags: equation-solving

The goal is to find the stationary points of the function
$$f(x)=\frac{y}{x-4\times10^{-5}}-\frac{1}{x^2}$$
for $y=7000$ using Mathematica. The input used was

```
f[x_] := (y)/(x - 4*^-5) - 1/x^2
y = 7000
Solve[D[f[x]] == 0, x]
Plot[f[x], {x, 8*^-5, 20*^-5}]
```

For $1<y<3500$, `Solve` outputs two real solutions as expected. For larger values of say $y>7000$ then `Solve` outputs complex-valued solutions, indicating that `D[f[x]]=0` has no real solutions. However, the plot shows that there are two real solutions, although only a precise level of zooming will show this.

Is the code incorrect for this purpose? Or is Mathematica just not able to solve the equation?

Comment: `f[x_] := (y)/(x - k) - 1/x^2
y = 7000
Solve[D[f[x]] == 0, x]`
You get two roots `(1 - Sqrt[1 - 28000 k])/14000` and `(1 + Sqrt[1 - 28000 k])/14000` but if 28000 * k is bigger than 1 so the square roots have negative numbers under them, hence if k is 4*10^-5 we get Sqrt[1 - 28000*4*10^-5] which is Sqrt[-(3/25)], and you get complex values.

Comment: i.e Mathematica is able to solve it fine. It's the plot that's deceiving you. The more weird thing is if you set y as high as it can go (y = 1/(4k)) while still allowing a real solution. This is 6250. Mathematica then returns 'two' solutions `{{x -> 1/12500}, {x -> 1/12500}}` which are exactly the same.

Comment: `D[f[x]]` doesn't do anything. If you want a derivative with respect to $x$, you need to specify it: `D[f[x], x]`.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's easier to look at this problem in terms of exact polynomial roots instead of numerical solutions.

The equation $\partial f/\partial x=0$ is a cubic polynomial in $x$ and therefore has three roots (real or complex). By expressing these roots as [`Root` objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1) we can ensure that we catch them all, for any combination of $y$ and $\epsilon$:

```
f[ε_, x_, y_] = y/(x - ε) - 1/x^2;
z[ε_, y_] = SolveValues[D[f[ε, x, y], x] == 0, x, Cubics -> False]
(*    {Root[-2 ε^2 + 4 ε #1 - 2 #1^2 + y #1^3 &, 1],
       Root[-2 ε^2 + 4 ε #1 - 2 #1^2 + y #1^3 &, 2],
       Root[-2 ε^2 + 4 ε #1 - 2 #1^2 + y #1^3 &, 3]}    *)
```

where I've written $\epsilon$ instead of $4\times10^{-5}$.

Now we plot them:

```
Plot[z[4*^-5, y], {y, 0, 10000}]
```

[image]

we see that there are three real roots for $y\lesssim7500$ and one real root above. This is quite common for cubic polynomials. The exact cutoff is found from the zero of the [polynomial discriminant](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Discriminant.html):

```
Solve[Discriminant[-2 ε^2 + 4 ε #1 - 2 #1^2 + y #1^3 &[x], x] == 0, y]
(*    {{y -> 0}, {y -> 8/(27 ε)}}

8/(27 ε) /. ε -> 4.*^-5
(*    7407.41    *)
```