# How to convert the result form of reduce calculation into the result form obtained by solve calculation?

Tags: differential-equations

Translate this result form:

```
d == 4 && a1 == -17 && s10 == 10
```

How to transform the above result form into this form?

```
{d -> 4, a -> -17, s1 -> 10}
```

Comment: Use the Method option with Solve: "With Method -> Reduce, Solve uses Reduce to find the complete solution set"

Comment: (-1) So you never try to understand answers you've obtained, right?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/288091/1871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eq = d == 4 && a1 == -17 && s10 == 10;
```

```
ToRules @ eq
```

> {d -> 4, a1 -> -17, s10 -> 10}

```
Rule @@@ List @@ eq
```

> {d -> 4, a1 -> -17, s10 -> 10}

```
eq /. {Equal :> Rule, And :> List}
```

> {d -> 4, a1 -> -17, s10 -> 10}

Answer (score 3):

```
List @@ (d == 4 && a1 == -17 && s10 == 10 /. Equal -> Rule)

(* {d -> 4, a1 -> -17, s10 -> 10} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
eq = d == 4 && a1 == -17 && s10 == 10;
```

---

Using `Cases`:

```
Cases[eq, a_ == b_ :> a -> b]
```

> `{d -> 4, a1 -> -17, s10 -> 10}`