# Eigensystem, Eigenvalue doesn't output nonreal eigenvalues

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, complex, algebraic-manipulation

Basically I have a matrix and when I used either `Eigenvalue` or `Eigensystem`, it doesn't output nonreal eigenvalues, instead it leaves it in the form of $$\sqrt{-1}^{1/3}$$ or something in terms of $\sqrt{-1}$

The matrix I have is

> ```
> F = {{-1/4, 1/4 + 1/Sqrt[2], -1/2 + 1/(2  Sqrt[2])},
>      {1/4 - 1/Sqrt[2], -1/4, -1/2 - 1/(2 Sqrt[2])},
>      {-1/2 - 1/(2 Sqrt[2]), -1/2 + 1/(2 Sqrt[2]), 1/2}}
> ```

I am trying to diagonalize this.

**EDIT** Adding `Simplify` seems to have solved half of the problem, it displays the eigenvectors in complex numbers, but the eigenvalues still in unsimplified form.

Comment: Why do you think $\sqrt{-1}$ is not non-real? In any case, use `N@Eigenvalues@F`.

Comment: What does '@' do?

Comment: if you type `F-Transpose[F]` you will find out that your matrix is not symmetric so its eigenvalues need not be real. And indeed they are not.

Comment: @jak `N @ Eigenvalues @ F` is the same as `N[ Eigenvalues[ F ] ]` and the same as `F // Eigenvalues // N`. So these are the three ways of using functions on some arguments.

Comment: So '@' is also '[' and ']'? I've never seen anyone used that before

Comment: Have a look at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be what you were expecting:

```
In[]:=
 {{-1/4, 1/4 + 1/Sqrt[2], -1/2 + 1/(2 Sqrt[2])},
  {1/4 - 1/Sqrt[2], -1/4, -1/2 - 1/(2 Sqrt[2])},
  {-1/2 - 1/(2 Sqrt[2]), -1/2 + 1/(2 Sqrt[2]), 1/2}} // Eigenvalues // ExpToTrig

Out[]=  
 {-1/2 + (I Sqrt[3])/2, -1/2 - (I Sqrt[3])/2, 1}
```

where `ExpToTrig[]` converts the exponentials like $(-1)^{2/3}$ accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

The appropriate function for symbolic representation of complex functions and numbers is `ComplexExpand`, e.g.

```
ComplexExpand @ Table[(-1)^(k/3), {k, 3}]
```

> ```
> {1/2 + (I Sqrt[3])/2, -(1/2) + (I Sqrt[3])/2, -1}
> ```

For this specific task `ExpToTrig` yields the expected  result, but for more general cases I recommend using `ComplexExpand` instead of `ExpToTrig`, for `F` (defined in the question) it yields the same :

```
ComplexExpand @ Eigenvalues @ F == ExpToTrig @ Eigenvalues @ F
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Consider for example this matrix :

```
m = Array[GCD, {3, 3}];
```

it yields eigenvalues of `m` in terms of `Root` objects, to get the result in terms of radicals one could add this option `Cubics->True` to `Eigenvalues`, `Eigensystem` etc. (this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/mathematica-wont-give-eigenvectors-but-wolfram-alpha-will-what-am-i-doing-wron/11500#11500) would be helpful as well).

Let's compare how `ExpToTrig` and `ComplexExpand` deal with `Eigenvalues` in this case :

```
ExpToTrig @ Eigenvalues[ m, Cubics -> True] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Therefore we can't even be sure that the eigenvalues are real numbers until we don't evaluate e.g. :

```
# ∈ Reals & /@ Eigenvalues[ m]
```

> ```
> {True, True, True}
> ```

we can see that `ExpToTrig` **is not really helpful here**, unlike `ComplexExpand` yielding symbolic eigenvalues, manifestly real:

```
ComplexExpand @ Eigenvalues[ m, Cubics -> True] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]