# How do I get the solutions of a cubic equation in trigonometric form?

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I know $x^3-3 x+1=0$ has three roots that can be expressed in trigonometric form:
$\{2\sin(10^\circ),\,-2\cos(20^\circ),\,2\cos(40^\circ)\}$.

How can I get this result with *Mathematica*?

Comment: Use e.g. `ComplexExpand@(x /. Solve[x^3 - 3 x + 1 == 0, x])`. This question concerns the same issue as  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17269/how-to-get-exact-roots-of-this-polynomial

Comment: Another related question : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14726/eigensystem-eigenvalue-doesnt-output-nonreal-eigenvalues

Comment: Thanks. But I want `Cos[π/9] + Sqrt[3] Sin[π/9]` can be simplify to `2 Cos[(2 π)/9]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply an identity directly:

```
ComplexExpand@
  Solve[x^3 - 3 x + 1 == 0, x] /. (A_: 1) Cos[t_] + (B_: 1) Sin[t_] :>
   Sqrt[A^2 + B^2] Cos[t - ArcTan[A, B]]

(* {{x -> 2 Cos[(2 π)/9]}, {x -> 2 Sin[π/18]}, {x -> -2 Cos[π/9]}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(ComplexExpand@Solve[x^3 - 3 x + 1 == 0, x] /. Pi/9 -> t // TrigFactor) /. t -> Pi/9

(*{{x -> 2 Cos[(2 π)/9]}, {x -> 2 Sin[π/18]}, {x -> -2 Cos[π/9]}}*)
```