# Dealing with answers that have Root[ ...] when finding an Eigensystem

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

This is a 3x3 matrix and I think it should solve for the expressions in terms of radicals. I am not sure what to do with this. 
[image]

Comment: @chris: `% // Normal` does nothing. Did you mean `% // ToRadicals`?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus oops… yes

Comment: Set the option `Cubics->True`. See also [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/mathematica-wont-give-eigenvectors-but-wolfram-alpha-will-what-am-i-doing-wron)